# how to toggle medium editor option on click using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, medium-editor

I am trying to toggle the medium editor option ([disableEditing](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor#note)) on button click. On the click the value for the medium editor option is changed but the medium editor does not use 'updated' value.

#### AngularJS Controller

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl',
   function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.isDisableEdit = false;
 });
```

#### Html Template

```
 <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <span class='position-left' medium-editor ng-model='editModel' bind-options="{'disableEditing': isDisableEdit, 'placeholder': {'text': 'type here'}}"></span>
   <button class='position-right' ng-click='isDisableEdit = !isDisableEdit'>
     Click to Toggle Editing 
   </button>
   <span class='position-right'>
     toggle value - {{isDisableEdit}}
   </span>
 </div>
```

I have created a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarsangp/7ffaa5aa/).

I think initialising medium editor on 'click' could solve the issue, but i am not sure how to do that either.

using [thijsw angular medium editor](https://github.com/thijsw/angular-medium-editor) and [yabwe medium editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor)

Answer (score 4):

For this specific use case, you could try just disabling/enabling the editor when the button is clicked:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor(iElement);

function onClick(event) {
    if (editor.isActive)  {
        editor.destroy();
    } else {
        editor.setup();
    }
}
```

In the above example, the `onClick` function is a handler for that toggle button you defined.

If you're just trying to enable/disable the user's ability to edit, I think those helpers should work for you.

MediumEditor does not currently support changing configuration options on an already existing instance. So, if you were actually trying to change a value for a MediumEditor option (ie `disableEditing`) you would need to `.destroy()` the previous instance, and create a new instance of the editor:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor(iElement),
    editingAllowed = true;

function onClick(event) {
    editor.destroy();
    if (editingAllowed)  {
        editor = new MediumEditor(iElement, { disableEditing: true });
    } else {
        editor = new MediumEditor(iElement);
    }
    editingAllowed = !editingAllowed;
}
```

Once instantiated, you can use `.setup()` and `.destroy()` helper methods to tear-down and re-initialize the editor respectively.  However, you cannot pass new options unless you create a new instance of the editor itself.

One last note, you were calling the `init()` method above.  This method is not officially supported or documented and it may be going away in future releases, so I would definitely avoid calling that method if you can.

Comment: it would be great if you could modify the fiddle to show how this can be done using angular-gridster

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use this dirty hack : **duplicate the medium-editor** element (one with disableEditing enabled, the other with disableEditing disabled), and **show only one at a time with ng-show / ng-hide** :)

```
<span ng-show='isDisableEdit' class='position-left' medium-editor ng-model='editModel' bind-options="{'disableEditing': true ,'disableReturn': isDisableEdit, 'placeholder': {'text': 'type here'}}"></span>
<span ng-hide='isDisableEdit' class='position-left' medium-editor ng-model='editModel' bind-options="{'disableEditing':false ,'disableReturn': isDisableEdit, 'placeholder': {'text': 'type here'}}"></span>
```

You can see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL07s798/).